About import error by using py-cord and discord.py
I was coding by using py-cord and discord.py to make Discord Bot in Python. But there's problem. I was making embed and button logics but someone just push me using 'view' library from discord. so here's my import code.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Button, ButtonStyle, Embed, View
import random
import datetime
import os
import pytz
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv

Where did it go wrong? the error said
cannot import name 'View' from 'discord'
Now, I'm not sure what should I try.
And this is my problem code.
@bot.slash_command(name="가위바위보", description="누리와 가위바위보 게임을 해보세요!")
async def rock_paper_scissors(ctx):
    embed = Embed(title="가위바위보!", description="무엇을 내시겠어요?", color=0x00ff00)

    # 버튼 생성
    view = View()
    button_rock = Button(label="바위", style=ButtonStyle.blurple)
    button_paper = Button(label="보", style=ButtonStyle.green)
    button_scissors = Button(label="가위", style=ButtonStyle.red)

    # 버튼에 클릭 이벤트 연결
    async def button_callback(interaction):
        user_choice = interaction.data['custom_id']
        # ... (skip some codes)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

    view.add_item(button_rock)
    view.add_item(button_paper)
    view.add_item(button_scissors)

    # 버튼이 포함된 메시지 전송
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

I tried to search other ways to use buttons without view library, but I can't find any good answers even in official site. So I'm in panic.

discord.py and pycord are two very different libraries. Which one are you using here?

Because it's discord.ui.View, not discord.View
from discord.ui import Button, View

